# Interpolate steps in depth measurement

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data from a linear measurement device:

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9)
```

Calculating the lagged and iterated differences with diff() will end up with something like:

```
c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0)
```

Which is not what I am looking for.
Is there a way to interpolate the depth to smooth steps like:

```
c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,6,7,8,9,9....)
```

Note: the data is the same as in the beginning, just the steps are interpolated to a continuous increase.
The reason for this is the resolution of the device is not enough to display the steps in between but having them as continues increase between two changes in time is more than enough to then take diff() to calculate the speed from the data of the linear measurement device.

Comment: Using `diff` as `ifelse(c(1, diff(x)), x, NA)`, you could take a look in `?approx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic solution that will still work if your difference between runs is > 1.

```
library(data.table)
rle_x <- rle(x)
vec <- unlist(sapply(1:(length(rle_x$values) - 1), 
                     function(i, x, rle) {
                          shift <- ((x[i+1] - x[i])/rle[i])
                          seq(x[i], x[i+1] - (shift), by = shift)
                       },
              rle = rle_x$lengths, x = rle_x$values))

res <- c(vec, rep(rle_x$values[length(rle_x$values)], rle_x$lengths[length(rle_x$lengths)]))
res
 #[1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.20 1.40 1.60 1.80 2.00 2.20 2.40 2.60 2.80 3.00 3.50 4.00 4.50 5.00 6.00
#[21] 7.00 8.00 9.00 9.00
```

If your input vector looked like: `x <- c(0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9)`. The result would be:

```
#[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 9.0
```

Comment: you could just use the rle(x)$values of the R base instead of the data.table library function rle_x$values.... but other than this point, this solution is perfect and the most appropriate to the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @renedlog thanks! I actually use data table for the `shift` function.

Comment: Oh, my bad... yeah I should have checked the code more carefully. I somehow didn't see the assignment `rle_x <- rle(x)`

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
fn=function(x){
  un=unique(x)
  for(i in 1:length(un)){
    if(i==1){vet=un[i]}
    else{
      vet=c(vet,seq(un[i-1],un[i],length.out=length(grep( un[(i-1)],x ))+1)[-1] )
    }
  }
return(vet)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the function `rle()` to find the *run-length* of each value, let's call it `lens`. Now we can calculate the cumulative sum of `1` divided by `lens` for each consecutive value, in `base R`:

```
lens <- rle(x)$lengths
cumsum(c(0, head(rep(1/lens,lens),-1)))
#[1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.20 1.40 1.60 1.80 2.00 2.20 2.40 2.60 2.80 3.00 3.50 4.00 4.50 5.00 6.00
#[21] 7.00 8.00 9.00 9.50
```

Answer (score 0):

A different suggestion using mapply.

```
> smoothFunc <- function(x) {
+   tab.x <- table(x) 
+   uni.x <- unique(x)
+   return(unlist(mapply(seq, from = uni.x, to = uni.x +  (tab.x - 1) / tab.x , length.out = tab.x)))
+ }
> 
> smoothFunc(x)
 [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.20 1.40 1.60 1.80 2.00 2.20 2.40 2.60 2.80 3.00 3.50 4.00 4.50 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00
[24] 9.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x <- x %>% group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(a = 1/n(),
           b = lag(a, default = 0),
           c = cumsum(b),
           d = x+c)
x$d
# [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.20 1.40 1.60 1.80 2.00 2.20 2.40 2.60 2.80 3.00 3.50 4.00
# [18] 4.50 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00 9.50
```